# How to Make mobile app from Codeigniter web based application with phonegap or basic 4 android?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cordova, phonegap-build, basic4android

I want to ask how to make the mobile application of CodeIgniter with phonegap or basic 4 android. I built a web-based information system applications with CodeIgniter framework. I'm having problems when creating mobile applications based on CodeIgniter

Comment: Phonegap does not use PHP. Please read the [FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/)

Answer (score 1):

basic4android or b4a through okHttp2 library or httputils library can send post request or get request to your server through php scripts so b4a can be ok for you

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer